# How to check what tile the player is standing on?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, tilemap

My goal here is to write a check of some sort in my playerMovement script so that I can check the name of the tile the that the bottom-middle of the sprite is located in on the tile map, from there I plan to use this to change footstep sounds based on the location which I believe I know how to do.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I haven't. I have no clue where to begin with this I'm pretty new to C# programming in Unity and trying to learn as I go

Comment: Are you looking for ["Detect which tile in a tile palette a player is colliding with"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/182922/39518)?

Comment: @DMGregory Unfortunately no, the game is top-down, so the tile the player is walking on isn't collidable it's simply in the background behind the character

Comment: Take the time to actually read the answer.  You don't need a collision for this to work. You can take the player's position and use the same code to look up the tile overlapping that position.

Comment: @DMGregory hmm you make a good point, I don't think I'm savvy enough yet to figure out how to implement that but I'll make an effort to get more familiar with the documentation of tile maps. Thank you